# How is the neutral wire obtained in a three-phase systems?

Tags: power-supply, transmission-line, three-phase

In India, we have only 3 transmission lines which are all live. But the domestic supply includes a neutral line along with that.

How can we can create a neutral in a transformer? Why don't we need a neutral at the generating stations or power stations? Why do we only need that at houses? Doesn't electricity need a way to go out also?

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power  Might want to read that and then narrow down your question to what you don't understand of the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *How we can create a neutral in a transformer?*

[image]

Image above from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfLi949b1Qg)

Primary is delta connected, secondary is star connected. Star connection provides neutral for homes and single phase loads. Neutral usually earthed at the transformer secondary.

> *Why don't we not need a neutral at the generating stations or power
> stations? Why only at houses we need that? Don't electricity need a way to go out also?*

There may be a neutral at the generating station, but it doesn't need to be transported hundreds of miles as a wire because we can recreate neutral with a local delta-star transformer near the house/office.

Comment: Why earthed neutral do not cause current leakage?

Comment: @AbinLatheef what leakage current do you refer to?

Comment: The current will be flowing to earth, won't it?

Comment: @AbinLatheef only if there is also a path from one of the live wires to earth through some leakage mechanism. Is that relevant to your original question?

Comment: @AbinLatheef are we done here now? Do you have an answer? I see in comments below the other answer you are asking about electric shock - is this relevant to your original question? Do you need to know anything else related to your original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117161/discussion-between-abin-latheef-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score 1):

Three-phase power is a curious beast. As long as all 3 phases are balanced a separate neutral return is not required. In a balanced system with a neutral, the current in the neutral would be zero. The grid is managed very carefully such that an imbalance does not occur.

Three-phase power is too complicated for household use. Single or dual-phase power is far easier and cheaper. Grid power is at a very high voltage, usually in the 10s KV. A transformer is required to step that down to something reasonable. In that transformer, a neutral is born. Depending on the setup it may be a single-phase and a neural or two-phases and a neutral. Because a transformer secondary is floating what makes it the neutral is that it is tied to earth (usually at the pole).

Comment: Why the current does not leak even if it is connected to the earth?

Comment: @AbinLatheef A transformer is a closed-loop type device. The net charge of the system is zero. Current can only come back to where it came from.

Comment: Then how we get electric shock? Current won't be flowing back there, right?

Comment: @AbinLatheef It's more complicated. A typical electric shock comes from touching a live circuit and an earthed chassis. The earth that protects the chassis is brought into the electrical panel and tied to the neutral. Because it is tied to the neutral it formes a return path back.

Comment: In Germany three-phase power is not too complicated for household use. For an electric water heater used to take a shower three-phase 22 kW is very common.